Tanstack Router Conditional Rendering
I have a routing setup with u/tanstack/react-router where I need to conditionally render components based on the active route. Specifically, I want the InstructorDashboardComponent to be rendered only when the route is /instructor-dashboard, and when the route is /instructor-dashboard/course-builder, the CourseBuilderComponent should be rendered instead.
Currently, with the given code, the InstructorDashboardComponent is always rendered at the top of the file, even when the route is /instructor-dashboard/course-builder, resulting in both the InstructorDashboardComponent and CourseBuilderComponent being displayed.
How can I conditionally render the InstructorDashboardComponent based on the active route to ensure it does not appear when the route is /instructor-dashboard/course-builder?
Here is the current setup for the routes:
Main Route:
import { createFileRoute, Outlet } from "@tanstack/react-router";
import MaxWidthWrapper from "../components/common/MaxWidthWrapper";
import InstructorDashboardComponent from "../components/InstructorDashboard/InstructorDashboardComponent";

export const Route = createFileRoute("/instructor-dashboard")({
  loader: async () => {
    // load with Tanstack query
  },
  component: () => (
    <MaxWidthWrapper className="h-screen">
      <InstructorDashboardComponent />
      <Outlet />
    </MaxWidthWrapper>
  ),
});

Sub Route:
import { createFileRoute } from "@tanstack/react-router";
import MaxWidthWrapper from "../components/common/MaxWidthWrapper";
import CourseBuilderComponent from "../components/InstructorDashboard/CourseBuilderComponent";

export const Route = createFileRoute("/instructor-dashboard/course-builder")({
  loader: async () => {
    // load with Tanstack query
  },
  component: () => (
    <MaxWidthWrapper className="h-screen">
      <CourseBuilderComponent
        courseContent={[]}
        courseTabInfo={{
          id: 123,
          courseName: "",
          longDescription: "",
          shortDescription: "",
          supportedGrades: "",
          supportedLanguages: "",
        }}
      />
    </MaxWidthWrapper>
  ),
});

What changes do I need to make to conditionally render these components based on the active route?
There is no documentation on this. I tried invoking a conditional rendering based on the props provided by TanStack router:
import { createFileRoute, Outlet } from "@tanstack/react-router";
import MaxWidthWrapper from "../components/common/MaxWidthWrapper";
import InstructorDashboardComponent from "../components/InstructorDashboard/InstructorDashboardComponent";

export const Route = createFileRoute("/instructor-dashboard")({
  loader: async () => {
    // load with Tanstack query
  },
  component: () => (
    <MaxWidthWrapper className="h-screen">
     ** {Route.fullPath === "/instructor-dashboard" ? (
        <InstructorDashboardComponent />
      ) : (
        <Outlet />
      )}**
    </MaxWidthWrapper>
  ),
});



But this will always evaluate to true because the subroute is nested inside the main route.

use useLocation hook from tanstack Router.
import { createFileRoute, Outlet } from "@tanstack/react-router";
import MaxWidthWrapper from "../components/common/MaxWidthWrapper";
import InstructorDashboardComponent from "../components/InstructorDashboard/InstructorDashboardComponent";

export const Route = createFileRoute("/instructor-dashboard")({
  loader: async () => {
    // load with Tanstack query
  },
  component: Component
});

function Component() {
  const location = useLocation()
  return(
    <MaxWidthWrapper className="h-screen">
         {location.pathName === "/instructor-dashboard" ? (
            <InstructorDashboardComponent />
          ) : (
            <Outlet />
          )}
     </MaxWidthWrapper>
    )

}

